# two text fields, one input, one output

Tags: swing, jpanel, jtextfield

I have to complete this code with these simple measures. Cannot do anything overly complicated. I want to translate from the top input text field and output on the bottom text field. So far, it looks right, but my translation simply outputs in the same text field as my input. I am a noob, and checked my notes and textbook, and cannot figure out how to change the output to the bottom field. It just doesn't seem to be possible with this level of code. The translation is right. I think I need to modify the Translate button, but am not sure where to indicate what. It works fine if I just wanted to output in my input box. Well, here is my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class Translator4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{


public static final int WIDTH = 500;
public static final int HEIGHT = 500;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_CHAR = 50;

private JTextField phrase;
private JTextField translatedphrase;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Translator4 gui = new Translator4();
    gui.setVisible(true);
}

public Translator4()
{
    //title bar and overall size
    super("Pig Latin Translator v.4.0");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

    //create input text filed
    JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
    namePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    namePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    phrase = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_CHAR);
    namePanel.add(phrase, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Enter the phrase in English to be translated:");
    namePanel.add(nameLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    add(namePanel);

    //create the buttons
    JPanel buttonPanel= new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    JButton actionButton = new JButton("Translate");
    actionButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(actionButton);

    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(clearButton);

    add(buttonPanel);

    //create the output text field      
    JPanel namePanel2 = new JPanel();
    namePanel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    namePanel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    translatedphrase = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_CHAR*2); //output will be larger so I multiplied it by 2
    namePanel.add(phrase, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JLabel nameLabel2 = new JLabel("Translation:");
    namePanel2.add(nameLabel2, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

    add(namePanel2);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();



    if (actionCommand.equals("Translate")) //when the user wants a translation, this block executes
    {

        String[] words=new String[100]; //takes up to 100 words
        String sentence = phrase.getText(); //the user input made into a string
        String newSentence=""; //the output string generated        
        words = sentence.split(" "); //splits based on spaces, no other punctuation allowed

        for (int index=0; index< words.length; index++) //steps thru the array of words
        {
            char firstChar = words[index].charAt(0); //rules for vowels, 'one' becomes 'oneway'
            if (firstChar=='a'||firstChar=='e'||firstChar=='i'||firstChar=='o'||firstChar=='u')
            {
                words[index] = words [index] + "way";

                newSentence=newSentence + " " + words[index]; //adds the word just now modified to new sentence

            }
            else //rules for words that don't start with vowels, 'blank' becomes 'lankbay'
            {
                firstChar = ' ';
                words[index] = (words[index]).substring(1,(words[index].length())) 
                        + (words[index]).charAt(0) + "ay";

                newSentence=newSentence + " " + words[index]; //adds the word just now modified to new sentence
            }

            phrase.setText(newSentence);    //sends the new sentence back for output... problem here
        }
    }

    else if (actionCommand.equals("Clear"))
        phrase.setText("");

    else
        phrase.setText("Unexpected error.");
}


}
```

Comment: It sends back the correct output already. It just puts it in the same box as the input, overwriting it.

Comment: How do I tie the output to the "translated" text field at the bottom instead of just sending it back to the top text field?

Comment: FIXED. I not only had to change the line to:\n

translatedphrase.setText(newSentence);

But my second field was set wrong. I changed it to:

translatedphrase = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_CHAR*2); 

namePanel2.add(translatedphrase, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JLabel nameLabel2 = new JLabel("Translation:");

namePanel2.add(nameLabel2, BorderLayout.NORTH); 


Thanks for the help. It got me looking in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

> but my translation simply outputs in the same text field as my input

That's because that's what you're telling it to do

```
phrase.setText(newSentence);    //sends the new sentence back for output... problem here
```

So I assume, `phrase` is the input and `translatedphrase` is the output, so that would mean, to fix your immediate issue, all you need to do is replace `phrase` with `translatedphrase`

```
translatedphrase.setText(newSentence);    //sends the new sentence back for output... no more problem
```

I would also suggest you change the other `setText` calls you're making against `phrase` to `translatedphrase` as well

This...

```
translatedphrase = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_CHAR * 2); //output will be larger so I multiplied it by 2
namePanel.add(phrase, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JLabel nameLabel2 = new JLabel("Translation:");
namePanel2.add(nameLabel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

is also an issue, as you never actually add `translatedphrase` to anything, you just re-add `phrase` to `namePanel` again

So, I assume it should be

```
translatedphrase = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_CHAR * 2); //output will be larger so I multiplied it by 2
namePanel2.add(translatedphrase, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JLabel nameLabel2 = new JLabel("Translation:");
namePanel2.add(nameLabel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```